# Best way to bind a XML File in Java (NetBeans)

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, binding

i want to bind this simple XML File in my java project:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<itg> 
 <reader> 
  <chapter id="1">
   <subchapter id="1"></subchapter> 
   <subchapter id="2"></subchapter>
  </chapter> 
  <chapter id="2">
   <subchapter id="1"></subchapter> 
   <subchapter id="2"></subchapter> 
  </chapter> 
  <chapter id="3"></chapter>
 </reader> 
 <questions> 
 </questions> 
</itg>
```

I use NetBeans, and actually i bind the XML File by parsing the xml file into a ArrayList, an bind the list.
It works, but it is possible to bind the xml File in a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For this small XML (and not only) I would recommend that you take a look at [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/). The two basic operations are marshalling (converting Java objects to XML data) and unmarshalling (converting XML data to Java objects) but verification and so on is also provided.